# How to release door catch on Samsung front loading washer

Tags: washing-machine

Washer door wouldn't latch closed. While trying to figure out what was wrong, I triggered the latch into the closed/locked position with the door open.  Anybody know how to get it to release?

Model number is wf409anw/xaa

Comment: Including the model number will help someone who is willing to do some internet searches for instruction/service manuals for you.

Comment: @FreeMan Good suggestion. Done.

Comment: Have you jiggled it? No, really, taken a screwdriver and attempted to _gently_ pry against whatever seems to be the locking mechanism? Have you tried unplugging & replugging? that might reset the computer and get it to unlock the latch.

Comment: Unplugging the power cord, waiting a couple of minutes, then plugging it back in usually does the trick. The microprocessor in the control board has something out of sequence, powering it down resets it. But don't power it back up too quickly, there is a capacitor that has to discharge first.